# how to sum array merge when data new same with data old in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have a case here, there are old and new data arrays, the old data contains item_code which is a unique field and contains summary data taken from the query. I will throw this data function recursively to find new data, which then I will merge to old data, so the problem is that when new data doesn't sum to old data, there will be twin ITEM CODE, so what's the solution like this when the merged array has to be sum group_by again? I have tried but failed

heres my code

```
$datareport = DB::connection('sales')->select(" EXEC master_mps_v '$dateto','$dateto','$datestock'");
    
//GABUNGKAN dan lempar variabledatanew agar terupdate terus pas merge
$datanew= array_merge($dataold,$datareport);
$datagroup=$datamps->groupBy('Item_Code');
$totalton = $datamps->sum('ton');
```

Comment: I think you might try converting your array to the collection after the merge 
& use https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby & https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum this functions.

Comment: i just do it but still not my excepted result

Comment: Please can you give an example of a before and after i.e. what you have initially, what you end up with and what you want to get.